# Inconsistent async behaviour when returning IHttpActionResult

Tags: .net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, owin, actionresult

I'm experiencing inconsistent async behaviour when returning IHttpActionResults from a web api 2 controller.

I have the following controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Route("foo")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetFoo()
    {
        string result = await Task.FromResult("foo");
        return Ok();
    }

    [Route("bar")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBar()
    {
        string result = await Task.FromResult("bar");
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

and this owin middleware plugged into the pipeline

```
public class TestMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public TestMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next)
        :base(next)
    {

    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        await Next.Invoke(context);
        ; // breakpoint here
    }
}
```

Note the breakpoint in the middleware.

If I make the following request (under debug): /api/foo, then the application stops at the breakpoint and the request is still open from the client perspective (fiddler in this case).

However, if I make a request to /api/bar, the request has returned with a response before the breakpoint has been reached.

The same is true for other action results that do not return a value.

Is this an expected behaviour? I do not like the inconsistency and above all, I have not seen this mentioned in the docs.